# index of out of range error based on selected button tag

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I am currently attempting to select a player by passing the button tag property inside of an array as shown in this line of code below:

```
selectedPlayer = players[sender.tag]
```

When I compiled the application, it crashes and displays a index out of range error, which I figure is because I'm accessing passed the size of the array. I am aware that make sure that I don't exceed the bounds of the array I need to do something like this:

```
players.count - 1
```

Although I am not entirely sure how to implement the same idea with the previous line of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about an if statement : `if sender.tag < players.count { selectedPlayer = players[sender.tag] }`

Comment: How did you assign tags to the buttons? the first one should has `0` value and so on...

Comment: @AhmadF I assign each button tag individually 0-5

Comment: So are you sure that `players` contains 6 elements?

Comment: @AhmadF yes I am sure.

Comment: So try to debug your code and check when the crash happens. Also, for the purpose of safety, you should do validation before assigning `selectedPlayer` (as mentioned in the answers).

Comment: for sure you have something wrong before this line `selectedPlayer = players[sender.tag]` do `print("Count",players.count,"tag",sender.tag)` then you'll be able to know the problem BTW you don't need any if or short ways to avoid the crash if you set everything correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ternary operator `?:`:

```
selectedPlayer = (sender.tag < players.count) ? players[sender.tag] : nil
```

If you want to use one liner code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array `players` of N elements make sure that

```
 0 <= buttonTag < N
```

so max value of the button tag should be = N - 1 , you can avoid the crash with

```
if sender.tag < players.count { 
  selectedPlayer = players[sender.tag] 
}
```

but the above may not accomplish the needed functionality , you have to adhere to the rule above